# Counting with Java

Tags: java, count, java.util.scanner

I have two given Strings: `String a = "111"` and `String b = "132"`, for these two String I want to achieve this count order:

```
111
112
121
122
131
132
```

Other example is if I have two given String like this: String a = "1111" and String b = "1223", I expect this result:

```
1111
1112
1113
1121
1122
1123
1211
1212
1213
1221
1222
1223
```

These can be also longer strings like `String a = "0100110"` and `String b = "01101120"`.

I'm waiting these Strings from user in condition that every character in String `a` should be lower or equal than the same character position in String `b` (String a = "11" and String b = "00" <= not allowed)

This is a recursive method till now but it doesn't work very well because it generates number twice or more depending on the input:

```
public void expand(String l,String h){
for(int i=l.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    sb = new StringBuffer(l);               
    if(charToDigit(l.charAt(i)) < charToDigit(h.charAt(i))) {           
        sb.replace(i, i+1, inc(sb.charAt(i)));  
        expand(sb.toString(),h);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your code so far? [Please read the guidelines on how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't have any good result till now! I'm waiting for something robust which can treat this problem in a good way.

Comment: Do you know how to program Java? Have you written something to at least take in input?

Comment: public void expand(String l, String h){
for(int i=a.length(); i>=0; i--)
{
sb = new StringBuffer(a);      
         if(charToDigit(a.charAt(i)) < charToDigit(b.charAt(i))) {           
             sb.replace(i, i+1, inc(sb.charAt(i)));  
             expand(sb.toString(),h);
         }
}

Comment: @ubadub Yes this is what I have done till now, but I wanted to simplify my problem and to not show any code.

Comment: Please put that in your question, not in a comment. Why would you not want to show any code? That's not how this site works.

Comment: A [mcve] is always better than a description.

Comment: @ubadub Here is the edited question, I hope it will help you can also try the code!

Answer (score 0):

Call the smaller number `x` and the larger number `y`. If you calculate `y` mod 10 (`y % 10`), you will find the value of the least significant digit, call this `n`. Similarly, calculate the least significant digit of `x`, call it `m` Then, create a temporary variable `i` which is equal to `x` initially. Loop until that number is equal to y.

In the body of the loop, first, print `i`. Then, if the least significant digit of `i` (again, calculated by `i % 10`), call it `o`, is less than `n`, increment `i` by one. Otherwise, if `o == n`, increase `i` by `10 - n + m`. Naturally, if it is ever the case that `o > n`, something went wrong (i.e. invalid input from the user), since the guarantee was that all digits of `x` are less than or equal to the corresponding digits in `y`.

So, in pseudocode:

```
x = smaller number
y = larger number
n = y % 10
m = x % 10
i = x

while (i <= y):
    print i
    o = i % 10
    if (o < n):
        i += 1
    else if (o == n):
        i += 10 - n + m
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
static String l="000";
static String h="232";
static ArrayList<String> combinations = new ArrayList<String>(); 
static int stringLength= l.length();

for(int i=0; i<rulelength; i++)
{
    combinations.add((charToDigit(h.charAt(i)) - charToDigit(l.charAt(i))+1)+"");
}
int number = 1;
for(int i=0; i<combinations.size(); i++)
{
    number*=Integer.parseInt(combinations.get(i));
}
int change = Integer.parseInt(combinations.get(combinations.size()-1));
expand(l, h, change, number);

public static void expand(String l, String h, int change, int comb)
{ 
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(l);
    int pos = stringLength-1;
    int tmpPos = pos;
    for(int i=1; i<=comb; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        sb.replace(pos, pos+1, inc(sb.charAt(pos)));
        if((i % change)==0) {   
            for(int j=stringLength-1; j>0; j--)
            {
                if(charToDigit(sb.charAt(j)) >= (Integer.parseInt(combinations.get(j))-1)) 
                    tmpPos = j-1;                   
                else
                    break;
            }
            sb.replace(tmpPos, tmpPos+1, inc(sb.charAt(tmpPos)));
            for(int j=stringLength-1; j>tmpPos; j--)
            {
                sb.replace(j, j+1, l.charAt(j)+"");
            }
        }
    }
}
```